# D3.js zoom functionality in node-map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently I'm working with nodes on a map, based on this D3.js example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022.

Now I want using the zoom functionality, but when I add this functionality as following code, it will only works a bit in Firefox. In all other browsers it does not work. I've also removed the drag method.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoom));

(...)

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

So the question is if it is possible to use the `tick` and `zoom` function both. So I can navigate through the nodes.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle of your own code?

Comment: I've placed it in a fiddle, based on my own code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvatrgw0/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a 'g' to which apply translate and scale transforms

Just add `.append('g')` after `.on("zoom", zoom))` (I have modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvatrgw0/2/) accordingly)

Another advice: zoom & pan work best without the `.transition()`

Comment: I have added your advice! Thanks, It is useful. It runs a lot more smoother now.

Comment: It's funny that my correct answer came first, then Vincent edited his answer to copy mine (you can see the fiddle sequence http://jsfiddle.net/gvatrgw0/3/ comes after http://jsfiddle.net/gvatrgw0/2/) and the final accepted answer is his and not mine... I can see it pays off to answer quickly, even if its wrong, and then edit the answer to copy the right one, instead of simply upvoting the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I change your zoom function according to this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999
Also add a g instead:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoom))
  .append('g') # Append g;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gvatrgw0/3/

Comment: Why you can't zoom on 'g' tags? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Didn't know that I need an extra `g`.